# Vue.js Slots: <template> tags used as slot content - How can I test this?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I have 2 main views which are using a shared layout component which has several named slots. I am passing the slot content through using wrapping `<template>` tags in many cases, as these don't result in unnecessary divs which would break the layouts quite badly. I am trying to write tests to test the two view components.

This works fine but I can't see the content in the output when doing a `shallowMount()` to test the component so all of my tests are falling over. Doing a full `mount()` isn't a viable solution at all here due to the components being 'page' level and having a lot of side effects (I would be unable to test the interactions that I need to test). I have also tried 'render' as an alternative method but that's no use either as I need to test significant functionality controlling visibility of different components.

This is quite odd behaviour.

Here's part of the receiving layout component...

```
<template>
    <aside :class="`layout-primary__aside ${this.rootClass}__aside`">
      <data-container :class="`layout-primary__aside__data ${this.rootClass}__aside__data`">
        <slot name="data" />
      </data-container>
      <slot name="aside" />
      <section :class="`layout-primary__cta ${this.rootClass}__cta`">
        <slot name="cta" />
      </section>
    </aside>
</template>
```

If I pass THIS into the slots (code from one of the view components I am trying to test)...

```
<template>
  <layout root-class="my-view"
          title="My View">
    <template slot="data">
      <data-item label="Total" :value="totalCost" />
    </template>
    <template slot="aside">
      Some random content
    </template>
    <branded-cta-tile slot="cta"
                      name="review"
                      class="cta__tile"
                      button-text="Review"
                      :show-back="true"
                      :breakout-extended="true"
                      @click="$router.push({ name: 'Review' })"
                      @back-click="$router.push({ name: 'Chooser' })" />
</template>
```

Then when I call `wrapper.html()` I can see the stubs rendered for the 'branded-cta-tile' but the other elements render simply as `<template></template>`

```
<layout-stub rootclass="plan-builder" title="Plan Builder"><template></template> <template></template> <branded-cta-tile-stub name="review" backbuttontext="Back a step" breakoutextended="true" buttontext="Review" showback="true" class="cta__tile"></branded-cta-tile-stub></<layout-stub>
```

I would EXPECT to see this...

```
<layout-stub rootclass="plan-builder" title="Plan Builder"><data-item-stub label="Total"></data-item-stub> Some random content <branded-cta-tile-stub name="review" backbuttontext="Back a step" breakoutextended="true" buttontext="Review" showback="true" class="cta__tile"></branded-cta-tile-stub></<layout-stub>
```

If I change the `<template>` tag with a slot name on it to `<div>` then it works fine. If I remove the slot name from the `<template>` tag then it renders the content inside the tag as you would expect - It seems to fail when you combine the two together.

Is there any workaround for this? If not the only option I realistically have is to duplicate the layout code and markup on 2 different views with what I can see right now.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `shallowMount`, the child components are stubbed with an empty template and will only render the default slot.

You have to provide a mock for `layout` containing the named slots, to render them.

From your question I assume that MyComponent is the component you are testing and you want to assert that the `layout` slots are rendering `<data-item label="Total" :value="totalCost" />`, `Some random content` and `<branded-cta-tile ...>`.
If not, please improve your question, because it is a little bit unclear to me. For example the name of the view component(s) you are testing is unknown. I call them MyComponent.

```html
// MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <layout root-class="my-view"
          title="My View">
    <template slot="data">
      <data-item label="Total" :value="totalCost" />
    </template>
    <template slot="aside">
      Some random content
    </template>
    <branded-cta-tile slot="cta"
                      name="review"
                      class="cta__tile"
                      button-text="Review"
                      :show-back="true"
                      :breakout-extended="true"
                      @click="$router.push({ name: 'Review' })"
                      @back-click="$router.push({ name: 'Chooser' })" />
</template>
```

```js
// MyComponent.spec.js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';
import DataItem from './DataItem.vue';
import BrandedCtaTile from './BrandedCtaTile.vue';

shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  stubs: {
    layout: {
      template: `<div>
                   <slot name="data"></slot>
                   <slot name="aside"></slot>
                   <slot name="cta"></slot>
                 </div>'
    }, // Use a mock that renders named slots
    DataItem, // Use the real component if you also want to render this component
    BrandedCtaTile // Idem
  }
});
```

It will replace the layout component with the stub, which is the only component in your SUT. If you don't do this, the layout component will not render the named slots and `shallowMount` will only render the default slot for the `layout` component (= nothing).

Comment: As with the other answer, I think you are missing the point. I am not testing the layout component I'm testing the component that is using it - I needed to test the slot content that the component under test is PASSING to layout. FYI: In the end I gave up with this completely and just duplicated the code as testing it seemed to be impossible.

Comment: If the component under test passes in the named slots using a 'div' wrapper, for example, this is perfectly testable bit of you use the 'template' tag instead it doesn't work, despite this being a perfectly valid thing to do (and good from a clean markup perspective). So far I have only been able to assume this is a bug with how Test Utils renders.

Comment: I think it is the opposite: you don't understand my point :)
It is not testing the layout component, but replacing it with the stub.
Please update your question if I still don't understand what you want to test exactly. For example provide a desired output for `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()`.

Comment: I'm not sure either way which direction this is coming from, but I've used named slots many times and never had to do this before (this is now an old question and the code no longer exists for me to confirm with) this doesn't answer to me as to why the named slots render stubs correctly when you use div wrappers instead of templates on the content to put into them. BrandedCtaTile, for example renders fine as a stub. The template slots (aside and data) render nothing at all. If I pass a div into aside instead that works fine. Unfortunately I can no longer confirm one way or another.

Comment: BTW - Your assumptions here are all spot on in terms of what I was trying to achieve. The last part of my question shows the output I got when passing in the data, rendering 'layout-stub' (expected) with 'branded-cta-tile-stub' (expected) and 2 instances of 'template' opening and closing tags (not expected) where I expected to see 'data-item-stub' in one instance and 'Some random content' in the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior when you use `shallowMount`.

It stubs all child components with their content. Since `layout` is a child component, it is stubbed with its content which includes the templates. Therefore, when you change templates to `div`s, you are able to see them in the snapshot.

If you want to get the `layout` component content in the snapshots, either test it in isolation and bind the content of the slots via `slots` [option](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#slots) of the `shallowMount` and `mount` API, or use a `mount` [function](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount).

Comment: You misunderstand the question - I'm not testing the layout component - I'm testing it's parent/consumer and, therefore, need to test what I am PASSING into layout's slots. The <template> tags do not belong to 'layout' they belong to the parent.Question could be clearer.